# Filtering through Calculations in MicroStrategy

Tags: microstrategy

I have a Microstrategy Dossier where I need to create a table which includes columns: Client, 12 Month sales, Current Month sales.

Current Month Sales should be according to the last month selected in a filter on the page.

I am trying to filter by the last month selected in the visible filter on the page.
The table I have now has: Client, 12 month sales, which is being filtered by a hidden filter of the last 12 months.
How can I add the column displaying only the last selected filter?

I have tried adding a filter which selects the max date, but it doesn't work since it should be taking the maximum date value in the dataset and not the last selected date value in the page filter.

I also tried creating a measure that Sums sales according to the max(date)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.